# Ассемблерная вставка и вычисление массива на С++

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Суть задания:

- 1. Найти сумму `z = 1+1/2+1/4 + . . .`
- 2. С помощью ассемблерной вставки вычислить массив `z[i] = sin (xi)`, где  `xi = PI * i / N`    где `N=10`
- 3. С помощью ассемблерной вставки вычислить  в  целочисленном массиве  `z[i]` число пар одинаковых соседних элементов.

На первое задание я написал функцию но не уверен в ее правильности

```
void f_double()
{    
    double z = 0;
    double x=2;
    __asm
    {  
        mov ecx, 10
        fld1
        fld1
        fldz                 

        lab1 :
            fadd   
            fxch st(1)          
            fdiv  x                 
            fst st(2)              
            fxch st(1)          
            loop lab1
            stp   z
     }
     printf("%10.7f \n", z);
}
```

Второе и третье задание не могу решить

Comment: А почему в первом задании нельзя просто напечатать "2" и сразу переходить ко второму?

Comment: @bipll задание явно просит запрограммировать алгоритм подсчета суммы, а не просто вывести ее значение.